# Remove a substring from a string with memmove in C

Tags: c, string, memmove

I'm trying to implement a function for removing a substring from a string with memmove.
When printing out the results, it seems like I have not moved correctly the substrings, even though it seems like I used the correct position in the source string.
My function is:

```
char * removeSubStr(char * str, const char * substr){
    char *scan_p, *temp_p;
    int subStrSize = strlen(substr);
    if (str == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (substr == NULL){
        return str;
    }
    else if (strlen(substr)> strlen(str)){
        return str;
    }
    temp_p = str;
    while(scan_p = strstr(temp_p,substr)){
        temp_p = scan_p + subStrSize;
        memmove(scan_p, temp_p, sizeof(temp_p)+1);

    }
    return str;
}
```

My output, for example is:
if sending the string "please remove rem remove rem999", 
I'm getting back: "please ove  rm ovmove re 999"

Thanks!

Comment: (Unrelated to your problem; but you should test `substr == NULL` before you pass `substr` to `strlen`. Otherwise you might end up calling `strlen` on a null pointer.)

Answer (score 4):

The following:

```
while(scan_p = strstr(temp_p,substr)){
    temp_p = scan_p + subStrSize;
    memmove(scan_p, temp_p, sizeof(temp_p)+1);
}
```

makes very little sense.

You need something like this:

```
while( temp_p = strstr( temp_p, substr ) )
{
    length = strlen( temp_p );
    memmove( temp_p, temp_p + subStrSize, length - subStrSize + 1 );
}
```

Note: in the first version of my answer I was just using `strlen()`, but as commenters pointed out, that would be inadvisable because of the standard.  (It would still most probably work, since we are copying down, not up, but it is best not to tempt your fate by violating the standard.)  So, that's why we need `memmove()`.

Note that with a couple of more lines of code this can be optimized so that you don't have to compute `length = strlen( temp_p );`  in each iteration of the loop.  This optimization is left as an exercise to the student.

Also please note:

- You better do `int subStrSize = strlen(substr);` ***after*** you check `substr == NULL`;
- There is no such thing as `styrlen()`
- `sizeof(temp_p)` does something completely different from what you think it does.

Comment: `strcpy( temp_p, temp_p + subStrSize );` is undefined behavior.  Per **7.24.2.3  The `strcpy` function** of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): "If  copying  takes  place  between  objects  that
overlap, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @AndrewHenle oh, I did not know that.  I will fix this.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNakis (styrlen is a typo :) ). I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
temp_p = str;
while(scan_p = strstr(temp_p,substr)){
    temp_p = scan_p + subStrSize;
    memmove(scan_p, temp_p, `sizeof(temp_p)`+1);

}
```

there are two bugs.

The first one is that after each iteration of the loop the pointer `temp_p` should be equal to the value of the pointer `scan_p` because the tail of the string is moved in this position.

The second one is that this expression

```
sizeof(temp_p)
```

yields the size of an object of the type `char *` instead of providing the length of the string pointed to by the pointer `temp_p`.

Also your function too often calls the function `strlen`.

As for the function design in whole then the function should not check whether one of the parameters is equal to NULL. It is the task of the client of the function. Standard C string functions do not do such a check.

The function implementation can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * removeSubStr( char *str, const char *substr )
{
    size_t m1 = strlen(str);
    size_t m2 = strlen(substr);

    if (!(m1 < m2))
    {
        for (char *p = str; (p = strstr(p, substr)) != NULL; )
        {
            size_t n = m1 - ( p + m2 - str );
            memmove(p, p + m2, n + 1);
        }
    }

    return str;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "12A12B12C12D";

    puts(s);

    puts(removeSubStr(s, "12"));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
12A12B12C12D
ABCD
```

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof(temp_p)` is the size of the `char *`, usually 4

You probably wanted to write `strlen(temp_p)`

Comment: strlen returns the length without the '\n', and sizeof includes the '\n' inside. isn't it?